# Java GUI Scaling problems

Tags: java, swing, windows-10

How i can disable scaling (Windows 10) for java program or process this in code to fix blur on my custom components?

I had tried `Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false` but it didn’t help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Java version you are using, you may want to consider different solutions, especially if you'd like to solve it on your application's side.

In any case, and if your concern is just to disable the Windows 10 scaling, you can do so by changing your Java settings and specifying Windows compatibility settings to override DPI scaling, as Elderry mentions here: https://superuser.com/a/1207925 , and as I'm quoting:

> 1. Find `java.exe` you installed.
> 2. Right click -> `Properties`
> 3. Go to `Compatibility` tab
> 4. **Check** `Override high DPI scaling behavior.`
> 5. Choose `System` for `Scaling performed by:`

You can refer to this link for additional answers which may resolve your problem: https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display