# How to make a picture not blurry in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I took a snip of a table in my application, and i want to display that snip in a tutorial section of the app. I can not get it to display with out being blurry. I don't know what is causing this. The picture is fine when i open it up in Windows photo viewer, but in the app it is blurry.

All my pictures are stored in a package called icons in my project, and they are not links to the pictures but actual copies.

Here is a minimal working example of my code. If anything that resizes the image, makes it lose quality how i can i prevent that?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class example extends JFrame {

     private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                try {
                    example frame = new example();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public example() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 558, 373);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(panel, gbc_panel);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 100, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel lblWordsGoHere = new JLabel("Words go here");
        lblWordsGoHere.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblWordsGoHere = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblWordsGoHere.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblWordsGoHere.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblWordsGoHere.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblWordsGoHere, gbc_lblWordsGoHere);

        Component horizontalStrut = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        horizontalStrut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_horizontalStrut = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_horizontalStrut.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_horizontalStrut.gridx = 0;
        gbc_horizontalStrut.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(horizontalStrut, gbc_horizontalStrut);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("More words here...");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(new     ImageIcon(example.class.getResource("/icons/Step3.png")));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);

        JTextArea txtrLotsOfDescriptive = new JTextArea();
        txtrLotsOfDescriptive.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        txtrLotsOfDescriptive.setText("lots of descriptive words....");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_txtrLotsOfDescriptive = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_txtrLotsOfDescriptive.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_txtrLotsOfDescriptive.gridx = 1;
        gbc_txtrLotsOfDescriptive.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(txtrLotsOfDescriptive, gbc_txtrLotsOfDescriptive);
    }

}
```

here is the image, the original snip from application, as you can tell it looks alright and this is how i would want it to look and display in the app.

[image]

now here is the snip from the image being displayed via the code in the tutorial screen. it's not as concise and it actually looks a bit worse than what is shown because the snip enlarged it. The snip makes it a little easier to read here, but you can still see that it doesn't look like the other picture. it has lost some quality and i don't know why or what to do about it. Any help and suggestions would go a long way! thank you!

[image]

Comment: Best to create and post a valid [mre] so we can see ***exactly*** how you're displaying the image. For instance, if you are displaying the image as an ImageIcon in a JLabel and you artificially change the size of the label, say by calling `setSize(...)` or `setBounds(...)` on the label, this will change the image size and degrade its quality.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was unaware that changing the label would affect the picture. I added code to show the layout manager. There is nothing else going on to the label except what is shown. I hope this is sufficient.

Comment: I'm afraid that you've still not posted a valid [mre] as no one can compile/run/reproduce your problem. Until you've posted a valid one, then the question is a duplicate of the others.

Comment: But again, if anything in your program resizes the image in any way, then this sort of thing can easily happen.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added a minimal example that still shows the problem, will you remove the duplicate?

Comment: Thank you for the program and I have removed the duplicate close, but when I run your code, I see no such image degradation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How can this be? i clearly see it as by my picture examples. what could be wrong on my end?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, *and you artificially change the size of the label, say by calling setSize(...) or setBounds(...) on the label, this will change the image size and degrade its quality.* - a JLabel always paints the Icon at its actual size.

Comment: @Kyle, Maybe you are using scaling on Windows 10 for example. This would probably cause problems. Maybe this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838951/java-gui-scaling-problems

Comment: @camickr you were right. Thank you so much. my scaling was on 125% i changed it to 100% and the picture is clear as day. i read over the links, and saw that windows is not scaling properly. how can i ensure that when a user installs my app, that windows will scale it correctly?

Comment: Really have no idea as I have not played with this before. However I do know that when you start a Java app you can use something like: `java -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.5 Example` to tell java to scale the app by 50%. Maybe if you use "1.0" it will use regular scaling no matter what Windows default is set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment from @camickr was the answer to my problem. My scaling was on 125% in my windows settings. I changed it to 100% and my picture quality improved greatly. Looks just it does in the photo viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, images are pixelated when I was using java jdk-16.0.2
The real problem is in JDK, when I change my JDK to OpenJDK all the images are displaying correctly.
You don't have to change windows scaling as it make everything small.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code where you import the image:

```
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/image.png")).getScaledInstance(90, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```